# How to Delete Image From SDCard in Android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

```
File file = new File(imagePath); 
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

using this code image delete on current screen But it not deleted from SDCard. 
so Please Anyone who know Answer please Post it.

Comment: Please refer this site  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707197/android-remove-an-image-from-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

file.delete(); 
Its not delete File or Images.