# Android: remove an image from sd card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I need to remove an image from sd card chosen by user.
In my Activity, after an user select an image from gallery, i execute this code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Utils.imgUri = data.getData();
            Utils.imgPath = getPath(Utils.imgUri);
            File file = new File(Utils.imgPath);
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

where *getPath* method is:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    else return null;
}
```

---

The images are correctly removed but in the gallery still remain a preview of the removed image.
When i tap on it, is loaded a black image..

so, How can I update the gallery previews, after I delete some images from my app code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved adding:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

It makes the MediaScanner service run again, which should remove the deleted image from the device's cache.

[same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430888/android-file-delete-leaves-empty-placeholder-in-gallery)

Comment: Doesn't work.  Leaves image in the gallery.   Instructions unclear above, I added your line immediately after the file.delete(); function is called.   If this is correct, code does not work as intended.

Answer (score 36):

Why would you make it that complex?

You can do it as simple as this:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Utils.imgUri, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` permission in the manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the file path is correct? Because the way you do the actual delete should be fine, see this SO thread:
[How to delete a file from SD card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

Should the /mnt/ really be there? Also, do you have the permissions to delete files from the storage? (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: Yes, I have this permission.
What do you mean with "/mnt/ really be there?". I get the path of the image from the Uri, with the getPath() method.

Comment: It seems that the path is wrong though, since file.exists() also returns false. Here another (but similar) way to get the path is used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-a-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android

Answer (score 0):

in the parameter "data" you have the Uri too, just do "`data.getUri()`". Also, are you testing in a real devices? if so and if it is a samsung, it isn't work (see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524105/how-could-i-get-the-correct-external-storage-on-samsung-and-all-other-devices)).

Comment: I get the Uri with "data.getUri()", then i get the path with "getPath()" method. Is there a way to delete a file using its Uri?

Comment: if using a File object with that uri doesnt work, then try using a contentResolver.delete(uri,null,null)

Answer (score 0):

simple one line ;)

```
 new File(uri.getPath()).delete();
```

and in manifest must use these permissions

android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Not all the uris are paths.

Comment: Yeah thats true but this is, in case of you are playing with SDCard.

Answer (score -1):

add below code in **onDestroy** method:

```
 if(myFile.exists())
 myFile.delete();
```

and don't forget to add permission in **Manifest** file

`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`