# How can I delete images after fullscreen

Tags: java, android, image, gridview

I have made an app with gridviews and a lot of pictures.

I have a fullscreenactivity and everytime I'm opening a picture in fullscreen it's saved in the camera folder but how can I delete it after fullscreen?

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                            mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                            "Share image using"));

    }
}
```

I hope that are all informations you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707197/android-remove-an-image-from-sd-card

Comment: How can i use it correct with my code?
And it should be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your full screen activity when ever come in increate() method then u will found one file path just delete that path from there from this code

```
    File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

After delete just refresh media gallery class like this using from this line i.e u can see the changes after delete of that picture.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath))));
```

also take permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: public static final String ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE 
Added in API level 1

Comment: Thank you for your help but i think i´m doing it wrong it crashes with
04-03 09:59:02.842: W/ContentResolver(7682): Failed to get type for: content://media/external/images/media/22272/storage/sdcard0 (Unknown URL : content://media/external/images/media/22272/storage/sdcard0)

Comment: i put it
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(path + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));

after the startActivity...?

Comment: just try to run only delete method not refresh and let me know what u found

Comment: It´s still the same only with
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse(path + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Comment: One wierd error is

04-03 10:12:55.747: E/AndroidRuntime(8494): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=8494, uid=10229

because i set permission in manifest

Comment: now see my edited ans and try to delete with this code dude and also refresh it

Comment: made it working with that code:
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));

But now i can´t share the pictures because it´s going deleted before the share how can i make it that it´s deleted after the share?

Comment: made that but it´s not working. it´s deleting the pic before the share action?
if i put it after share and } it´s not working too
if you add getContent... to your answer i will accept it as right :)
maybe you can help me with the new problem? or should i open a new question?
thx dude for ur help!

Comment: just use async task for sharing dude and in on post u jusr delete that file simple as that dude :)

Comment: what do i have to put in selectedfilepath?

Comment: ohk just pass your file path which u want to be delete

Comment: dude a lot to learn i have ^^ i don´t know what u mean that i use async for sharing i´m using async for class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask....
but your answer is mindblowing for me don´t have enough skill to understand it.

Comment: if i use my path (path) then i have The value of the local variable deleted is not used?

Comment: just pass the file path dude image file path which u want to delete

Comment: passed the path
storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera

still the same The value of the local variable deleted is not used :(

Comment: make it global variable dude

Comment: dude i really thank you for your help but for my skills that´s to much
but 2 last questions i´m thinking about
How could i save the pics in my own folder instead of the camera folder?
And is there no way to start
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));

after exit fullscreen? because that code is working...
Thank you really for ur time dude!!!!!!

Comment: i´m opening a new question is the best solution i think :D
but i mark your answer as right i´m sure it´s working...